# GPRS client identification

Tags: mobile

I would like to get advice about client identification connected over gprs network. Is it possible to solve identity in simple TCP packet or exist some higher protocol to obtain IMEI? There is many solutions, but I need to know if exist any standard solution or recommended use cases.

Thank you for any advice.

Martin Petřík

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On application layer you can read the IMEI of any Android device as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-get-the-devices-imei-esn-programmatically-in-android). For iOS maybe there is a similar method.

On lower level wireless operators can detect IMEI to use it for TAC/IMEI filtering when applying network features to specific devices or provide it to third parties as described in @LovaNirinaAndrianasolo 's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the IMEI can be obtained over the GPRS network but it has to be done **at the Network Operator level, not by the User at Service level**.

This process is called "Automatic Device Detection" and it is applicable to a GSM, GPRS or UMTS network.

You can refer to 4.1.2.1 in 3rd Generation Partnership Project (3GPP) TS 23.012 version 9.1.0 Release 9 to have more details about this standard solution.

In few words, if this function is activated at the network operator level, the IMEI is exchanged by the user equipment to the network operator equipment (MSC/VLR/HLR) through some signalling message.

The HLR finally sends the IMEI in XML format (SOAP) to a third-party server called ADD SERVER, the protocol used between them is HTTP or HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

The IMEI is below layer-3 (IP) or layer-4 (TCP) so it will not be transmitted beyond the carrier network to the public Internet.